# Stop appending when passing values to text file

Tags: php, append, text-files

I have a .php script which passes a value to a .txt file, this works only problem is that it appends the values, so if the current value is 1 then if I add 2 then the text file will look like this 12. How can I stop doing this, so if the current value is 1 and I add 2 then the value in the text file is 2.

my php function to pass value to .txt file:

```
<?php 

    $filename = "iPhoneAuctionBids.txt";
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    $content .= $priceVariable;
    file_put_contents($filename, $content);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get the contents of the file and add to it, just write to the file and you'll overwrite what's already there

```
<?php 

    $filename = "iPhoneAuctionBids.txt";
    file_put_contents($filename, $priceVariable);

?>
```